# Evoluir uma classe básica em Java

Tags: java

Olá,

Possuo a seguinte situação, tenho um objeto Animal e quero evoluí-lo para um Cachorro:

---

```
    public class Animal {
        private boolean alive = true;
        public boolean isAlive() {
            return alive;
        }
        public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
            this.alive = alive;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public abstract class Mamifero extends Animal {
        public abstract void mamar();
    }
```

---

```
    public class Cachorro extends Mamifero {
        @Override
        public void mamar() {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
```

---

Sei que isso (abaixo) não funciona:

```
Animal meuAnimal = new Animal();
Cachorro cao = (Cachorro) meuAnimal;
```

Mas eu não quero ter que instanciar um Cachorro e ir atributo-a-atributo preenchendo ele com os N dados que o meu Animal tiver.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa evolução automaticamente?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você quer. Se está **instanciando** um `Cachorro` de certa forma está instanciando um `Animal`. Em qualquer caso você terá que colocar os dados no objeto. Pode criar um rotina que faça isto ou pode criar valores *default* para os membros se isto for possível (você fez isto neste curto código). Em alguns casos pode ser necessário um construtor para iniciar estes valores *default*. Mas a pergunta não deixa muito claro o que deseja.

Comment: Eu possuo um objeto Animal (bruto), pois a classe que o instanciou é incapaz de especializá-lo. Após tratar esse Animal eu defino que ele deva ser um Cachorro, sendo assim quero especializá-lo agora. Existe alguma forma de eu instanciar um Cachorro com base em um objeto Animal já existente?

Comment: acho que a opção "menos pior" seria criar um construtor para animal que receba como parâmetro um animal. Assim quando fosse converte-lo para outros animais, você faria algo como: `Cachorro cao =  new Cachorro(animal);` E independente de que tipo de animal você instanciasse só precisaria ficar enviando o animal(parametro) até a classe Animal.

Comment: `Animal meuAnimal = new Cachorro();` mas voce so poderá utilizar os metodos presentes na classe Animal

Comment: @ChristianBeregula você vai responder?

Comment: Você está vivenciando um problema típico causado pelo uso da herança por ela mesma e não para solução de um problema real: a promoção de um objeto existente para um objeto de tipo mais especializado. Isso na prática não existe - **um cachorro já nasce cachorro, ele não nasce um tipo indefinido de animal para se transformar em cachorro mais tarde**. O mesmo é verdade na modelagem de um problema real num domínio real - se você notar a necessidade de promover um objeto para um tipo abaixo na hierarquia, é porque você usou herança quando não deveria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na realidade tinha pensado um pouco diferente. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
    public class Animal {
        private boolean alive = true;
        public Animal() {
        }
        public Animal(Animal animal) {
            this.alive = animal.alive;
        }
        public boolean isAlive() {
            return alive;
        }
        public void setAlive(boolean alive) {
            this.alive = alive;
        }
    }
```

A classe animal teria um construtor com um animal como parâmetro.

```
    public abstract class Mamifero extends Animal {
        public Mamifero() {
        }
        public Mamifero(Animal animal) {
            super(animal);
        }
        public abstract void mamar();
    }
```

Assim como todos os seus descendentes...

```
    public class Cachorro extends Mamifero {
        public Cachorro() {
        }
        public Cachorro(Animal animal) {
            super(animal);
        }
        @Override
        public void mamar() {
            System.out.println("Done");
        }
    }
```

E durante a execução do código você só precisaria instanciar seu novo tipo de animal.

```
Cachorro cao = new Cachorro(animal);
Gato gato = new Gato(animal);
Vaca vaca = new Vaca(animal);
```

E a única classe que se preocuparia em redistribuir esses valores seria a classe Animal.

Comment: Achei essa dúvida em outras perguntas também ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033118/how-to-downcast-a-java-object ), mas não foge dessa solução. No caso deste link o cara sugere uma classe de factory.

Answer (score 1):

"Existe alguma forma de eu instanciar um Cachorro com base em um objeto Animal já existente?"

Faça o seguinte: Crie um construtor na classe Cachorro que receba um Animal como parâmetro e passe os valores desse objeto Animal para essa classe Cachorro.

- Exemplo

Você tem essa classe Animal:

```
public class Animal {

  int atributo1;
  double atributo2;
  String atributo3;

  public void setAtributo1(int atributo) {
    atributo1 = atributo;
  }

  public int getAtributo1() {
    return this.atributo1;
  }

  public void setAtributo2(double atributo) {
    atributo2 = atributo;
  }

  public void getAtributo2() {
    return this.atributo2;
  }

  public void setAtributo3(String atributo) {
    atributo3 = atributo;
  }

  public void getAtributo3() {
    return this.atributo3;
  }

}
```

Sua classe Cachorro deve ser da seguinte forma

```
public class Cachorro {

  public Cachorro(Animal animal) {

    this.setAtributo1(animal.getAtributo1());   
    this.setAtributo2(animal.getAtributo2());
    this.setAtributo3(animal.getAtributo3());

  }

}
```

Dessa forma, na hora de instanciar os objetos você fará da seguinte forma:

```
Animal meuAnimal = new Animal();

meuAnimal.setAtributo1(/*VALOR*/);
meuAnimal.setAtributo2(/*VALOR*/);
meuAnimal.setAtributo3(/*VALOR*/);

Cachorro cao = new Cachorro(meuAnimal);
```

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer e fazer isso mas utilizar os metodos especiais de `Cachorro`